# casas decimais de um campo numeric variavel dependendo do CASE no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma consulta onde, dependendo de um parâmetro, eu preciso que o resultado em um campo seja com 5 casas decimais ou com 2 casas decimais, isso é possível no SQLSERVER 2008?

Exemplo

```
DECLARE @VALOR DECIMAL(18,2), @PORCENTOJUROS DECIMAL(18,2), @CODJUROS INT 

SET @VALOR = 5000.00
SET @PORCENTOJUROS = 2.0
SET @CODJUROS = 1

SELECT
CASE 
WHEN @CODJUROS = 1  THEN CAST((((@VALOR / 30.0) / 100.0) * @PORCENTOJUROS) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) 
WHEN @CODJUROS = 2  THEN  CAST((@PORCENTOJUROS / 30.0) AS NUMERIC(12,5)) 

ELSE 0.0 END [VALOR_MORA]
```

Neste Exemplo, se o @CODJUROS for 1 deveria me retornar um resultado com 2 casas decimais, e, se @CODJUROS for 2 deveria me retornar um resultado com 5 casas decimais, porem, os dois me retornam com 5 casas decimais.

Comment: Me parece um caso de [`Problema XY`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy). Você consegue explicar o porquê de você querer chegar a esta solução?

Comment: Essa consulta monta um layout customisavel para meus clientes por meio de pivot, este campo valor mora é escrito em um arquivo text, eu completo com "0" a esquerda para ficar sempre com 17 caracteres por isso as casas decimais influenciam no resultado final.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.

Um amigo aqui no trabalho chegou em uma "solução", convertendo o campo para varchar(MAX)

Segue resposta para ajudar outros:

```
DECLARE @VALOR DECIMAL(18,2), @PORCENTOJUROS DECIMAL(18,2), @CODJUROS INT 

SET @VALOR = 5000.00
SET @PORCENTOJUROS = 2.0
SET @CODJUROS = 1

SELECT
CASE 
WHEN @CODJUROS = 1  THEN cast(CAST((((@VALOR / 30.0) / 100.0) * @PORCENTOJUROS) AS decimal(15,2)) AS VARCHAR(max))
WHEN @CODJUROS = 2  THEN cast( CAST((@PORCENTOJUROS / 30.0) AS decimal(12,5)) AS VARCHAR(max))

ELSE cast(0.0  AS VARCHAR(max)) END [VALOR_MORA]
```